# Update Prepared Statement in Sql Server 2008

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, jakarta-ee, prepared-statement, updates

I am trying to update the table from my Java class.

```
con.prepareStatement("update New_Test_Master_School set School_Name=? where School_Code=? ");
ps.setString(1, bean.getSname());
ps.setString(2, bean.getScode());
System.out.println("before executeUpdate");
int i=ps.executeUpdate();
```

But `executeUpdate()` is not executing. I used if condition to check it. Its not executing. I got the values for bean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`executeUpdate` returns an integer value which is the number of rows successfully updated.. So, make your LHS an integer type: -

```
int result = ps.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Sorry i mentioned int only but its not giving values  i mean this code is not executing. I wanna know what's the wrong with this code. i am having many columns i want to update only school name based on the school code..

Comment: @Pavi.. There is a trailing space after your query. `School_Code=? `. See a space after `?`. Remove it, and then try.

Comment: I tried by removing it but its not executing. i executed the same code in server. its executing ... Dont know why its not working here